# Is there any way to customize login UI for AccountKit Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, account-kit

I have used accountkit with the provided account-kit ui.
Is there a way to use a separate layout screen (designed by us) say including another EditText fields for Name, Email, Location etc and also custom verification screen ?

Answer (score 3):

Till now, it's not possible to change the Account Kit UI to that extent. 
Modification is very limited made by Facebook. You can't even change the text below the number input.

You can **Change Color** of texts, buttons, **Change background**, **Set title**, **Predefine phone-number** etc. You can visit [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android) if you haven't to find out more about Account-kit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You can also use the Account Kit Advanced UI on Android and iOS which allows inserting Fragments or Views into most of the UI elements if you wanted to further customize the UI elements.

Comment: @OlgaKuznetsova can you please provide any sample examples if possible ?

Comment: This is the sample app for Android with some sample implementation for Advanced UI:https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android and here for iOS: https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-ios

Comment: @OlgaKuznetsova Can you please give me an example on how to change button colour in accountkit?

Answer (score 1):

The docs show how you can do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing
There are sections in the UI that are completely customizable and will give you a pretty liberal use of the screen.

Comment: `compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'` How can I find out which is the last version? As far as I know is not recommended to write 4.+